# Why does VSCode add an ampersand before the command when I run a program, which results in an error?

Tags: cmd, windows-10, visual-studio-code

I use Visual Studio Code 1.56.2 with Windows 10. I have a simple Python file that just outputs `hi`. When I try to run it in VSCode using the integrated terminal which I changed to cmd, it adds the character `&` before the python command

This is the terminal when I run the program:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1023]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\khalr\Python Projects>& C:/Users/khalr/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe "c:/Users/khalr/Python Projects/Test/main.py"
& was unexpected at this time.

C:\Users\khalr\Python Projects>
```

[image: This is the screenshot of the terminal window when I run the program.]

I also noticed that the terminal looks different since this started happening. There used to be icons on the top right beside the **X**. There used to be a garbage can icon among others.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this issue.

Comment: The `&` would be valid to invoke an executable in PowerShell, but not in cmd.exe (in cmd.exe, `&` is a command separator).

Comment: Your output is also showing in Windows Terminal, not cmd.exe. So there will be settings in VSCode and possibly also in Windows Terminal which could both change things. As this is not a site for software issues, you should seek assistance with the configuration of one or both of those installed software products on a more suitable platform, _[SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) perhaps!_

Comment: So if I just change the terminal to PowerShell it'll work?

Comment: did you do any drag and drop? If so, this could be a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/69187658/11107541