# Why does VS Code add a "&" prefix when dragging a file with spaces in its path from the Explorer View to an integrated PowerShell terminal?

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal

I'm using VS Code v1.60 on a Windows 10 PC. When I try to drag and drop files to the integrated terminal for their path, there is an *&* character which I have to delete manually, followed by the absolute path. This doesn't happen in Mac OS. Is this a bug, or do I need to change any settings to get rid of the prefix? [Check image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqFIU.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, this issue happens for windows users mostly, try this:

1. In vscode press `ctrl + p`.
2. type "settings.json".
3. add `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Git Bash"`.
4. save it and restart your vscode

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is by design for builtin PowerShell terminal profiles in VS Code. Quoting Daniel Imms from [their comment reply](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102486#issuecomment-658156729) to an issue ticket posted about the exact same question:

> This is by design as the & is required to run the file, some context: [#65994](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/65994)

If you go into [the changes made in that pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/65994/files#diff-941dd496a149f3d9cae0929751ef0f11fd930e234f6855b7ae780a87062acce9R691), you can see what exactly is being hardcoded as "being a PowerShell terminal":

> ```js
> const isPowerShell = pathBasename === 'pwsh' ||
>   this.title === 'pwsh' ||
>   pathBasename === 'powershell' ||
>   this.title === 'powershell';
> ```

See also [What does the & symbol in powershell mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22074507/11107541).

---

So I guess technically, you could work around this by defining a PowerShell terminal profile that doesn't match that definition of `isPowerShell`. Pretty gross, but I was successful in doing this by making a symlink to PowerShell with a name that isn't recognized by VS Code as "being PowerShell":

Open PowerShell with admin privileges and `cd` to a directory where you want to put the PowerShell symlink. Then run `ni ./pwsh2.exe -i SymbolicLink -ta "$Env:SystemRoot\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"`. Then you can put the following in a [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "My PowerShell Lookalike": {
        "path": "C:\\path\\to\\your\\pwsh2.exe", // TODO
        "icon": "terminal-powershell",
    },
},
```

You may or may not need to restart VS Code for the new profile to be recognized.

You can also change that terminal profile to be the default using the `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows` setting.

---

Or you could table-flip and change your `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows` to use a different terminal profile as the default instead of PowerShell.

I personally find the current state of things unsatisfying, and I don't really understand [Daniel's reply](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/102486#issuecomment-658156729), since the command is to `cd`- not to run the file. It seems to me that the behaviour that was hardocded is not very smart. But it doesn't help that I'm not a PowerShell SME. You could raise another issue ticket proposing some kind of better behaviour.

For your reference / learning purposes, I found that issue ticket by googling "`github vscode issues drag folder OR directory into terminal adds a "&" character`".

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.