# How can i fix character "&" when i run program on terminal Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKoHw.png)
So when I want to practice python in vs code, I run into a problem like the one in the picture where the "&" character is carried away, even though I just typed "python .vscode". Please help me because my lecturer will be holding a practice next week.

I have tried to find a way through YouTube but have not been able to find one that matches my problem

Comment: switch to using CMD instead of PowerShell as terminal in VSCode

Comment: why do you put your project files (`Main.py`) in the `.vscode` folder

Comment: did you drag the file into the integrated terminal to put its path there? if so, then this is a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/69187658/11107541

Comment: Your command is strange? How do you execute the code?

Comment: May I know what's going on with the problem? If it has been solved, can you change the status of the answer to help more people with similar problems.

Comment: did you drag and drop? if so, this is probably a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/69187658/11107541

Answer (score 0):

Your execution command is strange. First, make sure to use the **Python** extension to execute the script, and then try to ensure that your script path is in English and has no special characters or spaces.

[image]